# Is there any possibility to cut to a shape an image that can be moved with d3 (jquery)

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js, svg-filters

I am creating a bubble graph, the problem is that I wish to add some images inside the bubbles.

I am using this code: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

I bigger circle (around 20px radius) and I would like to have an image as filling of the circle and a black stroke (circle).

By now what I have is a Filter with inside a feImage that filter the circle. The problem is that the image move correctly but is still a square.

I tried adding a  with a circle inside, but when I apply the clipping the area of the svg clipped is fixed (I can see the image moving behind it).

How can I fix this?

`<filter id="Myriel" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
<feImage xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="img/vangogh.jpg"></feImage>
</filter>`

This is what result out from the d3 code, then is used with filter="url(#Myriel)" for example

Now I am using this, but is not working:

```
<filter id="Myriel" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
    <feImage xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="img/vangogh.jpg" result="img1">
    </feImage>
    <circle r="15" result="circ"></circle>
    <feComposite operator="atop" in="img1" in2="circ"></feComposite>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish the same task using svg `clippath`.

```
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.radius + 2;
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(1 / d.rating);
    });

node.append("clipPath")
    .attr('id', function(d, i) {
        return "clip" + i
    })
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "clip-path")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.radius;
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(1 / d.rating);
    });

node.append("svg:image")
    .attr("class", "circle")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8086/8466271529_dc5c0a958f.jpg")
    .attr("clip-path", function(d, i) {
        return "url(#clip" + i + ")"
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return -d.radius;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return -d.radius;
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
        return d.radius * 2;
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return d.radius * 2;
    });
```

I have made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ez4sd4g/2/) for the same. Hope this helps.

Comment: This example is awesome and solved me much more problem that I can imagine! I am working right now to fix my code!

Comment: Is there any way to disallow the bubble that I drag to snap back during dragging when I don't move the mouse but I'm still pressing the left button?

Comment: The problem was due to the panning and dragging actions of nodes at same time. Resolved the issue and updated the jsfiddle.

Comment: You can disable mouse over events on drag if needed. See commented code for doing that.

Comment: I've been looking your code stunned for at lest 10 minutes, I reached the same conclusion and code by my own just before you posted this!

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can clip an image to a shape within a filter using the feComposite primitive and operator="in". Google any of the many examples, or post your filter code and I'll add it for you.

Update:

Ok so your filter won't work because filters can only contain filter primitives. You can use shapes within your filter either by referencing SourceGraphic - which will pull in the element that the filter is referenced from or use feImage to pull in another shape by reference. The latter is somewhat buggy in IE, so for cross-browser, I recommend the former. Below are filters that do this.

Note that there are lots of ways to combine your clip and your outline. This does it by using a "green screen" technique - we use the red fill for the clip, but then get rid of it for the final using the color matrix. I'd actually recommend using a white fill and an feBlend - which results in a better visual appearance (IMHO). Both results below.

Also note that I got rid of the dimensions on your filter. Browsers generally don't include stroke width in their filter dimension calculation, so if you use 0%, 100%, you'll clip the stroke.

```html
<svg width="600px" height="800px">
  <defs>
<filter id="Myriel">
    <feImage xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/KPVrxlQ.png" width="500" height="500" result="img1"/>
    <feComposite operator="in" in="img1" in2="SourceGraphic" result="clip"/>
    <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0   0 1 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  -1 0 0 1 0" result="outline"/>
    <feComposite operator="over" in2="clip" in="outline"/>
</filter>
  </defs>
  <circle filter="url(#Myriel)" cx="200" cy="200" r="150" fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="4" />
</svg>
```

```html
<svg width="600px" height="800px">
  <defs>
<filter id="Myriel">
    <feImage xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/KPVrxlQ.png" width="500" height="500" result="img1"/>
    <feComposite operator="in" in="img1" in2="SourceGraphic" result="clip"/>
    <feBlend mode="multiply" in="SourceGraphic" in2="clip"/>
</filter>
  </defs>
  <circle filter="url(#Myriel)" cx="200" cy="200" r="150" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" />
</svg>
```

Comment: edited my post. Anyway, I will google it in any case, thanks for the tip

Comment: this is absolutely great! the second example is perfect, solved me many problem, I wish I can choose both the answers!